# how to invoke a function in a managed bean of sessionscope once page is loaded

Tags: jsp, jsf, managed-bean

I use a managedbean to provide the data for front page, and the data is saved in database. My managedbean is `@SessionScoped` for some reason and I can't change its scope.
But now I face a problem. For this situation, First, I load the page and browse the data(I read the data from my database in `@PostConstruct` method), then  I jump to another page and insert data into database. And then I back to page to browse the data and it won't change because the managed bean won't be created twice and I must reload the data. I think I can invoke a method once I load this page. How to achieve it?

Comment: Are you using JSP as you view technology or Facelets?

Comment: Thank you. I have solved this problem.

Comment: Please post an answer for your question then.